# Can you give an example regarding this point: lambda-expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

A point from n3290:ISO Standared draft, §5.1.2/9

> A *lambda-expression* whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (3.3.3) 
>          is a *local lambda expression*; any other *lambda-expression* shall not have a 
>          *capture-list* in its *lambda-introducer*. The *reaching scope* of a local
>          lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the 
>          innermost enclosing function and its parameters. [ *Note*: This reaching scope includes any intervening *lambda-expression*'s — *end note* ]

Can any one give an exmaple for the above point, especially:  **"other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-list in its lambda-introducer."**
Where does this situation arise?

Comment: Strange. As I understand that paragraph, [this](http://ideone.com/xhuq6) should not work, and yet, it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation should theoretically arise in namespace scope, as @Space_C0wb0y shows in [his comment link](http://ideone.com/xhuq6).

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 12;
auto l = [&x](){ return x; };

int main() {
    std::cout << l() << std::endl;
}
```

If find it strange that GCC accepts that snippet, as MSVC correctly rejects it with the following error message:

> error C3480: 'x': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope